# In which countries was "The Story of Ferdinand" banned?

Tags: censorship, the-story-of-ferdinand, munro-leaf

On the [Wikipedia page for *The Story of Ferdinand*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Ferdinand#Reception), it says this:

> The book was released nine months before the outbreak of the Spanish Civil War, and was seen by many supporters of Francisco Franco as a pacifist book.<sup>[8]</sup> **It was banned in many countries**, including in Spain (where it remained banned until after Franco's death).<sup>[7]</sup> In Nazi Germany, Adolf Hitler ordered the book burned (as "degenerate democratic propaganda"), while it was the only American children's book available for sale in Stalinist-era Poland.<sup>[7]</sup>
>   <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Going to the reference marked <sup>[7]</sup>, which is [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/entertainment/books/1986/11/09/ferdinand-the-bulls-50th-anniversary/3325d6dc-cc68-4be7-9569-408439896098/?utm_term=.47e6b7651e78), there's this:

> In Nazi Germany, Hitler burned the translation for being "degenerate democratic propaganda." When Berlin fell in 1945, 30,000 copies were immediately printed and freely distributed among the children in a mission of peace. In its 50 years, it has been translated into 60 languages and is said to have sold at least 2.5 million copies world-wide. It has been pirated -- and rewritten -- in the Soviet Union. It was the only American children's book available in Stalinist Poland, and a square in Warsaw has been renamed "Ferdinand." It remained banned in Spain until Franco's death.

...but I don't see anything about the 'many countries' that the Wikipedia page claims that it was banned in.

**Is this Wikipedia page accurate, that it was banned in many countries? Which countries has it been banned in?**